# How to sum up all ints in a text file?

Tags: java, arrays, file

I need to pull integers from a text file and sum them up. I came up with this but I keep getting an error. What am I missing? I need to use a scanner class.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class txtClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        
        File txtFile = new File(//text file path//);
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(txtFile);
        
        int length = 0;
        while(scan.hasNextLine()) {
            scan.nextLine();
            length++;
        }
        
        
        int array[] = new int [length];
        array[length++] = scan.nextInt();
        
        System.out.println(array.toString());
        int h = 0;
        
        for (int i = 0; i<array.length; i++)
        {
            h +=array[i];   
        }
        scan.close();
        System.out.print(h);
    }

}
```

Comment: You can't scan the same file twice with the same `Scanner`.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: You don't need to store all the values if all you're going to do is add them up.  You can just read one number at a time, and add it to your running total.

Comment: Start by actually adding the input on each line to the total as you go `int runningTotal = 0; while(scan.hasNextLine()) {runningTotal += scan.nextInt();}`

Answer (score 1):

As suggested, a lot of the code is not really needed.  But presumably the 'error' you get is array index out of bounds.  Here:

```
    int array[] = new int [length];
    array[length++] = scan.nextInt();
```

So you allocate an array and **immediately** access off the end of the array. Let's assume `length` is 42. Therefore, the allocated array elements have indexes 0 to 41.  You try and assign something to array[42].  I'm not sure what you're trying to do with that line.

The alternative guess (which we would not need to guess had you mentioned the actual error message) is that your counting lines leaves the scanner positioned at end of file. so the `scan.nextInt()` call in the assignment gets you an I/O error.

In any case, the core of the solution is something like

```
int sum = 0;
while (scan.hasNextInt())
   sum += scan.nextInt();
```

No array is needed.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote in your question

> I keep getting an error

That would be [NoSuchElementException](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/NoSuchElementException.html) which is thrown by this line of your code:

```java
array[length++] = scan.nextInt();
```

This is because you have already [scanned](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/scanning.html) the entire file and therefore there is no next `int`.

Remember that in order for people to help you with errors thrown by your code, you need to post the actual exception and the stack trace as well as your code.

You don't need to save all the numbers in the file in an array in order to get the sum of all the numbers. However if you also want to save all the numbers but you don't know in advance how many there are, you can use a [List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/list.html).

Here is a minimal example of how to read the file – which I assume contains only numbers separated by whitespace – and calculate the total. Of-course you need to replace *text file path* with the actual path to the text file.

```java
File txtFile = new File("text file path");
try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(txtFile)) {
    int total = 0;
    while (scan.hasNextInt()) {
        total += scan.nextInt();
    }
    System.out.println("Total: " + total);
}
catch (FileNotFoundException xFileNotFound) {
    xFileNotFound.printStackTrace();
}
```

Note that the above code uses [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).